# Is a SortedDictionary automatically sorted?

Tags: c#

I have never used a SortedDictionary and was just curious if when you add values to it, for example, in a for loop, do the values get sorted automatically when you add them or do you have to sort them after you add them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's done automatically.  The dictionary is structured in such a way that it must be sorted to operate correctly.

Comment: I would expect it to be implemented as a tree. Probably a red-black or AVL tree.

Comment: Yes, as @itsmatt indicates, MSDN says it's a binary search tree.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  Microsoft discusses the SortedDictionary [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx).

A couple quotes from that page that indicate that sorting is taking place automatically:

> "The SortedDictionary<(Of <(TKey,
>   TValue>)>) generic class is a binary
>   search tree with O(log n) retrieval,
>   where n is the number of elements in
>   the dictionary."

O(log n) lookup indicates (typically) that we're in some tree looking for a match via a binary search.

and

> "SortedDictionary<(Of <(TKey,
>   TValue>)>) has faster insertion and
>   removal operations for unsorted data:
>   O(log n) as opposed to O(n) for
>   SortedList<(Of <(TKey, TValue>)>)."

Again, O(log n) for the insertion, since it has to iterate through the structure to find the insertion point.

Good fun.

Answer (score 2):

Being in sorted order is an invariant of `SortedDictionary`, so you never need to sort it explicitly.